# how to use apiReources method with `only`?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm creating an api with Laravel and I am looking for an easy lazy way to to register Api resources.
I'm currently defining my routes like this:

```
Route::apiResource('categories', 'CategoryController')->only(['index', 'show']);
```

I checked [Laravel's controller documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) and I saw `apiResources` method which I can create multiple api resources at once.

the goal:
is to be able to use `apiResources` with `only` method like this

```
Route::apiResources(['categories' => 'CategoryController', 'products' => 'ProductController'])->only(['index', 'show']);
```

current result:

> Call to a member function only() on null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

long story short (if you don't want to read the whole story) you can just do it like this:

```
Route::apiResources(['brands' => 'BrandController', 'categories' => 'CategoryController'], ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

When I was writing the question it passed to my mind to check the `apiResources` declaration and I found this:

```
   /**
     * Register an array of API resource controllers.
     *
     * @param  array  $resources
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function apiResources(array $resources, array $options = [])
    {
        foreach ($resources as $name => $controller) {
            $this->apiResource($name, $controller, $options);
        }
    }
```

and since it is using `apiResource` under the hood and it is passing options parameter I can check what are these options

```
/**
 * Route an API resource to a controller.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration
 */
public function apiResource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
{
    $only = ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'];

    if (isset($options['except'])) {
        $only = array_diff($only, (array) $options['except']);
    }

    return $this->resource($name, $controller, array_merge([
        'only' => $only,
    ], $options));
}
```

Comment: The second argument (options) applies to all the resources? I just don't want one of them to use the "update" method. Maybe we can't do it with `apiResources`.

Comment: No this will be applied only to the resource you are using `apiResource` with.
in the answer for **brands** resource, I just needed `index` and `show` methods to be defined by this resource. and the other `apiResource` won't be affected. it depends on the options you're passing to it.

Comment: I am talking about `apiResources` not `apiResource`. We are not in the same page.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding first, Yeah you are right about that **options** argument is for all of resources passed in the first argument.